# swiftmailer Auth issues with hotmail

Tags: php, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I've searched high and low and I can't seem to find a working example of a swiftmailer script that uses a **hotmail** smtp, I have tried using the google one's in examples and upating the port, user and password but the page just hangs until it times out.

My code:

```
  require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
// Create the SMTP configuration
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("smtp.live.com", 465, "TLS");
$transport->setUsername("xxxx@hotmail.com");
$transport->setPassword("XXXXXX");

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setTo(array(
   "XXXX@company.com" => "xxx",
));
$message->setCc(array("another@fake.com" => "Aurelio De Rosa"));
$message->setBcc(array("boss@bank.com" => "Bank Boss"));
$message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");
$message->setBody("You're our best client ever.");
$message->setFrom("XXXXX", "XX XXXXXXX");


// Send the email
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);

// Show failed recipients
print_r($failedRecipients);
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you need to set your encryption param correctly. For port 465 use `ssl`; for 587, `tls`. hotmail isn't any different to anywhere else - your code would not work anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and info, I have updated the script and tried both 465 with ssl and 587 with tls, both result in a connection time out #110.  Is there any other settings or configs I should be aware of?